# Flutter - How to test Hydrated Bloc?

Tags: flutter, dart, testing, bloc

I want to mock Hydrated Blocs but I receive an error when running those unit tests.

```
Storage was accessed before it was initialized.
Please ensure that storage has been initialized.

For example:

final storage = await HydratedStorage.build();
HydratedBlocOverrides.runZoned(
  () => runApp(MyApp()),
  storage: storage,
);
```

I found a solution on GitHub, but it also displays an error
https://github.com/felangel/bloc/blob/master/examples/flutter_weather/test/helpers/hydrated_bloc.dart

```
void initHydratedStorage() {
  TestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  hydratedStorage = MockStorage();
  when(
    () => hydratedStorage.write(any(), any<dynamic>()),
  ).thenAnswer((_) async {});
  HydratedBloc.storage = hydratedStorage;
}
```

Gives this:
`The setter 'storage' isn't defined for the type 'HydratedBloc<Event, State>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I upgraded my hydrated bloc package from 8.1.0 to 9.0.0-dev.3 and it seems to work now. The problem was that the  `storage` property is not available in the 8.1.0 version.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).